# How to create a CloudRun with terraform export a secret as env var?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-run

I'm want to create a Cloud Run using terraform. The example is working from here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service#example-usage---cloud-run-service-basic

I have the following secret: /projects/my-project-id/secret/VAR, and would like to export this secret as VAR env var.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this section inside of containers:

```
        env {
          name = "VAR"
          value_from {
            secret_key_ref {
              name = "VAR"
              key  = "1"
            }
          }
        }
```